# Object reading and writing overload in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading

I know that the assignment operator can be overloaded. When writing to an object, the object's overload function is called.

```
Obj = 10; // Obj's assignment overload function called.
```

Is there a way to define a function to be called when an object is read?

```
int a = Obj;
```

In this case `Obj`'s reading function would be called and the return value would be assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for what's sometimes called a [cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct example
{
    int val;
    operator int() const { return val; }
};

int main ()
{
    example x{42};
    int y = x;
    std::cout << y;
}
```

Will print 42.